# Access Titles and Values from a MultiValueSpecifier preference in Settings.bundle

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, plist

I've got the following setup in my `Root.plist` file as part of my app's `Settings.bundle`:

```
<dict>
    <key>PreferenceSpecifiers</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>Type</key>
            <string>PSMultiValueSpecifier</string>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>Title</string>
            <key>Key</key>
            <string>my_key</string>
            <key>DefaultValue</key>
            <string>default_value</string>
            <key>Titles</key>
            <array>
                <string>Default Value</string>
                <string>First</string>
                <string>Second</string>
                <string>Third</string>
                <string>Fourth</string>
            </array>
            <key>Values</key>
            <array>
                <string>default_value</string>
                <string>one</string>
                <string>two</string>
                <string>three</string>
                <string>four</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>StringsTable</key>
    <string>Root</string>
</dict>
```

I would like to get access to the `Titles` and `Values` so that I can effectively determine the `Title` (i.e. the string representation) of a particular preference, and assign a text view's text to that value.

For example,

```
*defaultValue = [NSUserDefaults valueForKey:@"my_key"]; 
// let's say it's 'one'
textView setText:[[self getTitleForValue:defaultValue]]; 
// i want getTitleForValue to return 'First'
```

Do I have to parse the `Root.plist` file myself? and then build/reconcile the mapping between Titles and Values manually?

The settings list is long enough that I would prefer not to have to write an if statement after doing a lookup in `NSUserDefaults`, so I definitely want to find a solution that will allow me to look it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those interested, This is what I ended up with

```
NSString *bPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSString *settingsPath = [bPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Settings.bundle"];
NSString *plistFile = [settingsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Root.plist"];
NSDictionary *settingsDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistFile];
NSArray *preferencesArray = [settingsDictionary objectForKey:@"PreferenceSpecifiers"];
NSArray *titles = [[preferencesArray objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"Titles"];
NSArray *values = [[preferencesArray objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"Values"];
int index = [values indexOfObject:currentValue];
if( index > -1 ){
    return [titles objectAtIndex:index];
}
return @"Default Title";
```

Answer (score 1):

**For Title:**

```
NSLog(@"%@",[[[[yourdic objectForKey:@"PreferenceSpecifiers"] objectAtindex:0] objectForKey:@"Titles"] objectAtIndex:0]);
```

//OR

```
NSLog(@"%@",[[[yourdic objectForKey:@"PreferenceSpecifiers"] objectAtindex:0] objectForKey:@"Titles"]);
```

**For Value:**

```
NSLog(@"%@",[[[[yourdic objectForKey:@"PreferenceSpecifiers"] objectAtindex:0] objectForKey:@"Values"] objectAtIndex:0]);
```

//OR

```
NSLog(@"%@",[[[yourdic objectForKey:@"PreferenceSpecifiers"] objectAtindex:0] objectForKey:@"Values"]);
```

Comment: I need to cast it to an NSArray in order to use objectAtIndex. Alternatively you can use `firstObject`.. but thanks for the idea -- can you make the appropriate edit and I'll accept the answer?